# Get Wordpress page featured image into footer.

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to display the featured image for a page inside the footer.

I have the following code in my footer.php, but it's not displaying anything at all. I'm a newb to php/the loop. Any ideas?

```
<?php
   ?>
    </div><!-- #main -->

    <div id="footer">
        <?php get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full'); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="contact">
        <p>For information please contact ...</p>
    </div>

</div><!-- #wrapper -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display it , echo the get_the_post_thumbnail();

Try

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code.

```
<?php
?>
</div><!-- #main -->

<div id="footer">
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' ); ?>" alt="">
</div>

<div id="contact">
    <p>For information please contact ...</p>
</div>

</div><!-- #wrapper -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code Below

```
</div><!-- #main -->

<div id="footer">
    <?=get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'full');?>
</div>

<div id="contact">
    <p>For information please contact ...</p>
</div>
```